# How can I preserve JupterLab's dark theme when exporting to HTML?

Tags: html, css, themes, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have JupyterLab's built-in dark theme enabled, but when I export a notebook to HTML, I get the normal, light theme version.

I found the [css.variables file for the dark thme in jupyterlab's GitHub repo](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/master/packages/theme-dark-extension/style) and added that to the html output I get from exporting, but nothing changes.

Is there a way to force the dark theme when exporting to HTML from JupyterLab?